# Protocol for closing a socket connection

Tags: linux, sockets, open-close

I'm rolling my own application protocol on top of TCP.  I'm using Linux and C.  I'm wondering whether there is an advisable sequence to closing a socket connection.

The client will always initiate the close by sending a specially-formed string; say, "CLOSE".  I'd like to receive some kind of acknowledgement from the server that it has seen my CLOSE request, so perhaps it needs to send back a special string like "CLOSE_OK".

I've also seen both the close() and shutdown() system calls, but am not sure how to use them. For instance, should the client, after receiving "CLOSE_OK", do a shutdown(OUTPUT) and then wait to receive a zero-length string?  And should the server, after sending "CLOSE_OK", issue close() and then consider the socket to be dead?

I'm hoping there's a "best practice" on this subject that I haven't found yet...

Thanks,
Chap

Comment: This question would be better on Stack Overflow, where it would be a duplicate of this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160347/close-vs-shutdown-socket

Comment: I debated whether this belonged here or on SO.  The link you gave doesn't completely answer my question, which I think is more of a general programming/protocol question than just the specifics of close and shutdown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to handshake at the application layer (for instance, in order to get a confirmation from the other end that some persistent data has been committed), do that using your `CLOSE` and `CLOSE_OK` protocol messages. Indeed you need to do this at the application layer (see the end-to-end principle). But after both ends of the socket are already in agreement that the connection, don't waste any time or effort gracefully closing one direction of communication, verifying that that happened, and then gracefully closing the other end. Just `close()` the socket from both ends. Depending on the timing, the TCP `FIN` and `ACK` sequences may or may not occur sequentially or cross each other on the wire, but your application shouldn't care about that. In any case, just `close`ing will be the fastest thing you can do.

`shutdown` is useful in cases where you really do need to signal that communication has finished in one direction but the other direction is still needed. It can be used, for example, by a client that is talking to a server that will not send any reply until it gets all of the data from the client, complete with an EOF at the end. `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` makes that EOF happen without having to close the whole socket (bidirectionally).

Comment: Very clear explanation!  One question: although I like CLOSE/CLOSE_OK, it sounds as if I (the client) could just issue shutdown(OUTPUT) and wait to receive EOF, while the server, on reading my EOF, could send <final_message> + EOF.  Or are there circumstances under which the server could receive EOF without my having intentionally caused it by issuing shutdown or close?

Comment: If the server must be able to tell the difference between a clean client shutdown and a rupture of the connection (think database transaction: a client gracefully disconnecting should cause a COMMIT as the server's last action but a connection rupture should cause a ROLLBACK) then use something explicit in the protocol. If that doesn't matter for your protocol, your idea of just sending `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` is perfectly fine and will work correctly.